# How to define a left handed coordinate system in sympy.physics.vector module?

Tags: python, vector, orientation, physics, sympy

I am trying to do some vector field manipulations using the sympy.physics.vector module [from here](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/physics/vector/api/classes.html). As part of the process I would like to keep track of a number of coordinate systems and a subset of these are going to be left handed.

Let's say I start with:

- reference frame A (right handed; x: right, y: into page, z: up)

  and
- reference frame B (left handed; x: right, y: into page, z: down)

  ```
  from sympy.physics.vector import ReferenceFrame
  A = ReferenceFrame('A')
  B = ReferenceFrame('B')
  ```

Now I need to define the relationship between these systems and the only way I am aware this can be achieved is by using *orient* to define a set of rotations between the two reference frames. Now, I don't need to tell you that no amount of rotations would transform a right handed system to a left handed system... What I simply need is to let know reference frame B that

```
 B.z = -A.z
```

which I can't do with

```
B[2] = -A[2]
```

since <<'ReferenceFrame' object does not support item assignment >>

It doesn't seem that using *CoordinateSym* would help me much here either...

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sympy.physics.vector package is built around right handed systems. I don't think you can expect a left handed system to work, as all operations follow the right hand rule, e.g. cross products. Implementing general functionality for left handed systems will need significant updates to the underlying code.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my suspicions.
Besides the cross product, the rotations must also be redefined for left handed systems. It mostly involves adding minuses to all these operations in case the system is of different orientation. I don't think it requires that much rewriting.
Maybe the documentation should emphasise these limitations as not all coordinates systems will be right handed in practice. And would be really nice to be able to keep track of the system orientation as well within the module.

Comment: Feel free to submit an pull request with improvements to the documentation.